# How to overcome type change for function argument when moving it to HashMap?

Tags: rust

The following code describes a container for prepared asynchronous calls using a HashMap:

```rust
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    any::Any,
    marker::Send
};
use futures::future::{Future, BoxFuture};

// ===================================

pub type AnyType = Box<dyn Any + Send>;

// ===================================

trait AsyncFn {
    fn call(&self, arg: AnyType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>;
}

impl<T, F> AsyncFn for T
where
    T: Fn(AnyType) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send,
{
    fn call(&self, arg: AnyType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
        Box::pin(self(arg))
    }
}

async fn async_test(data: AnyType) -> () {
    let d: Box<String> = data.downcast().unwrap();
    println!("String data = {d:?}");
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut callables: HashMap<String, Box<dyn AsyncFn>> = HashMap::new();
    callables.insert(
        "test_func".to_string(),
        Box::new(async_test)
    );

    let awaitable = callables.get("test_func").unwrap();
    awaitable.call(Box::new("test string argument1".to_string())).await;
}
```

I was faced with the task of preparing for a future call in this way not only an asynchronous function, but also an additional, related argument. I tried to do it like this:

```rust
use std::{any::Any, collections::HashMap};
use futures::future::{Future, BoxFuture};


pub type AnyType = Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync>;
pub type AnyBindType = Option<AnyType>;

// ===================================

trait AsyncBindFn {
    fn call(&self, arg: AnyBindType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>;
}

impl<T, F> AsyncBindFn for T
where
    T: Fn(AnyBindType) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send + Sync,
{
    fn call(&self, arg: AnyBindType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
        Box::pin(self(arg))
    }
}

async fn async_test2(data: AnyBindType) -> () {
    if let Some(ref d) = data {
        let d = d.downcast_ref::<String>();
        println!("String data = {d:?}");
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let mut bind_callables: HashMap<String, (Box<dyn AsyncBindFn>, AnyBindType)> = HashMap::new();
    bind_callables.insert(
        "bind_test_func".to_string(),
        (
            Box::new(async_test2),
            Some(Box::new("test bind string argument1".to_string())),
        ),
    );

    let bind_awaitable_data = bind_callables.get("bind_test_func").unwrap();
    let (bind_awaitable, bind_arg) = bind_awaitable_data;

    // if let Some(ref d) = bind_arg {
    //     let d = d.downcast_ref::<String>();
    //     println!("String data = {d:?}");
    // }

    bind_awaitable.call(bind_arg).await; // ! ERROR
    //                  ^^^^^^^^ - mismatched type
}
```

After the data is transferred to the `HashMap`, the only way to get the original is by doing a `remove()` on it, but I need to be able to reuse it. Means, it is required to me to have access through ref.

In the last example, the commented out last block of `if let` successfully prints this data, but since it is a reference, I can't send it to do the same in the corresponding function, as it's a type mismatch.

It follows that the description of the signature should be changed accordingly so that the function takes a reference to an optional argument, but then when I receive it, I will have a reference to a reference to the optional data, and so on...

How to overcome this situation?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're worried about. You can always get a `&T` from an `&&T`,  because `&T` is copy, if that's where you're stuck.

Comment: I tried this and… [wat](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26564d60e538c4398eb325b973e29bda)?

Comment: @Caesar sorry. Corrected to a complete, working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`impl Future` should be used explicitly in the return value definition:

```rust
use std::{any::Any, collections::HashMap};
use futures::future::{Future, BoxFuture};


pub type AnyBindType = Option<Box<dyn Any + Send + Sync>>;

// ===================================

trait AsyncBindFn {
    fn call(&self, arg: &AnyBindType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()>;
}

impl<T, F> AsyncBindFn for T
where
    T: Fn(&AnyBindType) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static + Send + Sync,
{
    fn call(&self, arg: &AnyBindType) -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> {
        Box::pin(self(arg))
    }
}

fn string_test(data: &AnyBindType) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    if let Some(d) = data {
        let data = d.downcast_ref::<String>().unwrap().clone();
        println!("String data = {data:?}");

    };
    return async move {};
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let mut bind_callables: HashMap<String, (Box<dyn AsyncBindFn>, AnyBindType)> = HashMap::new();
    bind_callables.insert(
        "bind_test_func".to_string(),
        (
            Box::new(string_test),
            Some(Box::new("test bind string argument".to_string())),
        ),
    );

    let bind_awaitable_data = bind_callables.get("bind_test_func").unwrap();
    let (bind_awaitable, bind_arg) = bind_awaitable_data;

    bind_awaitable.call(bind_arg).await;
}
```